# Python reaching local variable before throwing error

Tags: python, mysql, try-catch

I am learning `Python` and Mr. Terminal says I'm referencing the local variable "data" (line 6) before defining it.

I can't figure out why an error isn't being thrown before it reaches this variable.

Here is relevant code:

```
    def querySQL(query,value,tag):
        try:
            connection = mdb.connect(servername, username, password, dbname)
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query,value,tag)
            data = cursor.fetchall()

        except mdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
            sys.exit(1)
            return e.args[0]

        finally:   
            if connection:    
                return data
                connection.close()
            else:
                print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
                sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: It's throwing an error before it reaches `data = cursor.fetchall()`. Even if an error is thrown, the `finally` block still executes because `finally` *always* executes, that is its purpose.

Comment: Also putting `connection.close()` after your `return data` won't actually close the connection because you will have already returned from the function.

Comment: Which line does the error message point to?

Answer (score 0):

There is an exception thrown, probably in the `execute`-line, because `connection` is already defined, and a call to `cursor` is not very likely to fail. Since the `finally`-block is always executed, even in case of an exception, the original exception is hidden by the `UnboundLocalError`. That's why it is important to only include cleanup code in the `finally`-block.

```
def querySQL(query,value,tag):
    try:
        connection = mdb.connect(servername, username, password, dbname)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query,value,tag)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
    except mdb.Error, e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
        sys.exit(1)
    finally:   
        if connection:
            connection.close()
    return data
```

You probably want to give the arguments of `execute` as a list:

```
cursor.execute(query, [value, tag])
```

Comment: That worked and I'll keep that in mind to limit the finally block for clean up purposes. Thanks Daniel!

Comment: As a side note, cursor.execute() is complaining that I gave it 4 arguments..... value & tag are 'strings'  and query = "INSERT INTO homepage (cream,cow) VALUES(%s,%s)"